# shareopint powershell pointing the field of an element inside the collection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have a question about the follow code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$list = $web.Lists["Style Library"]
$fields = $list.Fields.InternalName
$fields | Where {$_ -like '*workflow*'}
```

output:

```
WorkflowVersion
WorkflowInstanceID
```

As I know, `$fields` is a `SPFieldCollection`

Why I can access the field belongs to `SPField` using a syntax like this: `$list.Fields.InternalName?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing an `SPFieldCollection` with `SPField`. `SPFieldCollection` doesn't have a member called `InternalName`, but `SPField` does.

Instead, your PS query should look like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$list = $web.Lists["Style Library"]
$fields = $list.Fields
$fields | ? {$_.InternalName -like '*workflow*'}
```

You don't get `InternalName` for the whole collection. You get the collection first and then iterating through it you get the `InternalName` for each of the item.

Comment: hi @Paul Strupeikis ,  thanks for your reply. yes I'm confused. Oh i think understood it already. So the $_ sign is the mean of each object inside the SPFieldCOllection, so that the InternalName is accessible through the $_ sign. Actually your code gave me a better understanding comparing to my sample code.